# ¿Como usar entityFramework con PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

Estoy realizando un sistema desktop con **VStudio2017** y necesito usar un **ORM** para facilitar el acceso a la base de datos. Busque en internet la manera de configurar **entityFramework**. Despues de instalar la extensión: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Procedo a agregar un modelo de datos:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tras agregar el modelo de datos debo añadir la conexión a la base de datos, para ello debo utilizar un Data Source:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que solo me brinda para **SQL** y necesito configurarlo para **postgreSQL**. Si alguien pude ayudarme sería de gran ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Olvídate de los designers, usa EF Core: http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Lo que necesito es hacer la ingeniería inversa, ya tengo una base de datos necesito tener las entidades. Seguí las intrucciones de la web que me hiciste llegar y me muestra este error:
No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.

Comment: existe un paquete aparte, lo pódes encontrar aquí: http://www.npgsql.org/ef6/
Funciona exactamente igual que entity framework para SQL, pero no podés utilizar funciones, al menos no cuando trabajé con esto.

Comment: Debes usar los parámetros --project y --startup-project de acuerdo a la estructura de tu proyecto. Si el projecto donde esta tu modelo de EF es diferente al projecto ejecutable deberas usar estas opciones. Mas info en: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#using-the-tools

Comment: en `--project` coloca la ruta del `.csproj` del proyecto donde quieres que se generen las clases. En `--startup-project` coloca la ruta del `.csproj` del proyecto ejecutable, ya sea windows forms, asp.net, WPF, etc

Comment: @Alex te refieres a que puedo crear un Entity Data Model con postgreSQL???

Comment: @AS13L si, a eso me refiero, cuando estes creando el modelo cambias la conexión como lo pones en la tercera captura adjunta en tu pregunta y seleccionas la de Postgres. Funcionará relativamente igual. Es un poco más limitada pero funciona.